# How do I avoid a circular template dependency between serializers and serializers of containers?

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, stl, circular-dependency

I am writing template classes for de/serialization of stl containers.

Let's say I want to serialize a `set<int>`. I have a base `serialisation` class and the following template:

```
template<typename T>class serialiser;

template<>class serialiser<int>:public serialisation<int>{
public:
  void serialise ( int t );
};
```

To serialize the `set`, I have:

```
template<typename T>class Container_serialiser:public serialisation<T>{
public:
  void serialise ( T t );
private:
  /* Notice that I must declare a serialiser.
   */
  serialiser<typename T :: value_type>value_serialiser;
};

template<typename T>void Container_serialiser<T>::serialise ( T t ){
  for(typename T :: const_iterator t_iterator = t . begin ( );t_iterator != t . end ( );++ t_iterator){
    value_serialiser . serialise ( * t_iterator );
  }
}
```

***This only works for containers with elements that do not themselves comprise containers.***

## The Problem

What if I want to serialize a `map<int,set<int> >`?

Since each element's type is `pair<int,set<int> >`, I need the following class:

```
template<>class serialiser<pair<int,set<int> > >:public serialisation<pair<int,set<int> > >{
public:
  void serialise ( const pair<int,set<int> >t );
private:
  serialiser<int>t_first_serialiser;

  /* Notice that I must declare a Container_serialiser.
   */
  Container_serialiser<set<int> >t_second_serialiser;
};
```

However, `Container_serialiser` requires `serialiser<T>` to be a complete type. Thus, it cannot be defined until after the above class. Likewise, the above class requires `Container_serialiser<T>` to be a complete type and cannot be defined before it.

The compiler gives the following error:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'class Container_serialiser<std::map<int, std::set<int> > >':
prog.cpp:73:44:   required from here
prog.cpp:40:39: error: 'Container_serialiser<T>::value_serialiser' has incomplete type
   serialiser<typename T :: value_type>value_serialiser;
                                       ^
prog.cpp:25:27: note: declaration of 'class serialiser<std::pair<const int, std::set<int> > >'
 template<typename T>class serialiser;
```

### Problem Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

using std :: cout;

using std :: map;

using std :: set;

using std :: make_pair;
using std :: pair;

template<typename T>class serialisation{
public:
  virtual ~serialisation ( );
protected:
  virtual void serialise ( const T t ) = 0;
};

template<typename T>serialisation<T> :: ~serialisation ( ){
}

template<typename T>class serialiser;

template<>class serialiser<int>:public serialisation<int>{
public:
  void serialise ( const int t );
};

void serialiser<int>:: serialise ( const int t ){
  cout << t << '\n';
}

template<typename T>class Container_serialiser:public serialisation<T>{
public:
  void serialise ( const T t );
private:
  serialiser<typename T :: value_type>value_serialiser;
};

template<typename T>void Container_serialiser<T>:: serialise ( const T t ){
  for(typename T :: const_iterator t_iterator = t . begin ( );t_iterator != t . end ( );++ t_iterator){
    value_serialiser . serialise ( * t_iterator );
  }
}

template<>class serialiser<pair<int,set<int> > >:public serialisation<pair<int,set<int> > >{
public:
  void serialise ( const pair<int,set<int> >t );
private:
  serialiser<int>t_first_serialiser;

  Container_serialiser<set<int> >t_second_serialiser;
};

void serialiser<pair<int,set<int> > >:: serialise ( const pair<int,set<int> >t ){
  t_first_serialiser . serialise ( t . first );
  t_second_serialiser . serialise ( t . second );
}

int main ( ){
  set<int>t;
  t . insert ( 2 );
  t . insert ( 3 );
  Container_serialiser<set<int> >t_serialiser;
  t_serialiser . serialise ( t );

  map<int,set<int> >u;
  u . insert ( make_pair ( 5,t ) );
  u . insert ( make_pair ( 7,t ) );
  Container_serialiser<map<int,set<int> > >u_serialiser;
  u_serialiser . serialise ( u );
}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/7FRuoU)

## A Hack

I can make this work by writing four templates:

1. `serialiser0<T>` for all T that are not containers and do not comprise containers
2. `Container_serialiser0<T>` for all T whose `value_type` is the argument of a `serialiser0<T>`
3. `serialiser1<T>` for all T that are not containers but comprise containers of elements that themselves do not comprise containers
4. `Container_serialiser1<T>` for all T whose `value_type` is the argument of a `serialiser1<T>`

***This design is repetitive, confusing, and has to be extended manually for each new level of containers. Is there a better pattern?***

Unfortunately, due to the project I am working on, I must avoid external dependencies such as [boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) even at the cost of taking a performance hit and write for the C++98 standard.

### Hack Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

using std :: cout;

using std :: map;

using std :: set;

using std :: make_pair;
using std :: pair;

template<typename T>class serialisation{
public:
  virtual ~serialisation ( );
protected:
  virtual void serialise ( const T t ) = 0;
};

template<typename T>serialisation<T> :: ~serialisation ( ){
}

template<typename T>class serialiser0;

template<>class serialiser0<int>:public serialisation<int>{
public:
  void serialise ( const int t );
};

void serialiser0<int>:: serialise ( const int t ){
  cout << t << '\n';
}

template<typename T>class Container_serialiser0:public serialisation<T>{
public:
  void serialise ( const T t );
private:
  serialiser0<typename T :: value_type>value_serialiser;
};

template<typename T>void Container_serialiser0<T>:: serialise ( const T t ){
  for(typename T :: const_iterator t_iterator = t . begin ( );t_iterator != t . end ( );++ t_iterator){
    value_serialiser . serialise ( * t_iterator );
  }
}

template<typename T>class serialiser1;

template<>class serialiser1<pair<const int,set<int> > >:public serialisation<pair<int,set<int> > >{
public:
  void serialise ( const pair<int,set<int> >t );
private:
  serialiser0<int>t_first_serialiser;

  Container_serialiser0<set<int> >t_second_serialiser;
};

void serialiser1<pair<const int,set<int> > >:: serialise ( const pair<int,set<int> >t ){
  t_first_serialiser . serialise ( t . first );
  t_second_serialiser . serialise ( t . second );
}

/* This is the same as Container_serialiser0!
 */
template<typename T>class Container_serialiser1:public serialisation<T>{
public:
  void serialise ( const T t );
private:
  serialiser1<typename T :: value_type>value_serialiser;
};

template<typename T>void Container_serialiser1<T>:: serialise ( const T t ){
  for(typename T :: const_iterator t_iterator = t . begin ( );t_iterator != t . end ( );++ t_iterator){
    value_serialiser . serialise ( * t_iterator );
  }
}

int main ( ){
  set<int>t;
  t . insert ( 2 );
  t . insert ( 3 );
  Container_serialiser0<set<int> >t_serialiser;
  t_serialiser . serialise ( t );

  map<int,set<int> >u;
  u . insert ( make_pair ( 5,t ) );
  u . insert ( make_pair ( 7,t ) );
  Container_serialiser1<map<int,set<int> > >u_serialiser;
  u_serialiser . serialise ( u );
}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/CfmJyO)

Comment: Can't you avoid definition of `Container_serialiser` and make all of the classes be specialization of `serialiser`? And have a separate specialization for each container type? In this case you can define `serializer<int>`, `serializer< pair<T1, T2> >`, `serializer< set<T> >` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I must admit that I had forgotten about this question.)

Thanks to @michael-gopshtein's comment, I eventually stumbled upon [partial template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization), which solves this problem quite well. Note that I must use both `template <typename SerialisedType> class Serialiser` and `template <typename SerialisedType> inline void serialise(const SerialisedType &x)`. The function itself cannot be partially-specialized, but most specializations of `Serialiser::serialise` depend upon a general call to `::serialise`.

To serialize a `std::map<int, std::set<int>>`, I would write the following:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

// For the sake of having a MWE, I'll just write int-s to stdout.
#include <iostream>

template <typename SerialisedType> class Serialiser;

template <typename SerialisedType>
inline void serialise(const SerialisedType &x) {
  Serialiser<SerialisedType>::serialise(x);
}

template <> class Serialiser<int> {
public:
  inline static void serialise(const int &x);
};

template <typename Key> class Serialiser<std::set<Key>> {
public:
  inline static void serialise(const std::set<Key> &x);
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> class Serialiser<std::pair<T1, T2>> {
public:
  inline static void serialise(const std::pair<T1, T2> &x);
};

template <typename Key, typename T>
class Serialiser<std::map<Key, T>> {
public:
  inline static void serialise(const std::map<Key, T> &x);
};

void Serialiser<int>::serialise(const int &x) {
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}

template <typename Key>
void Serialiser<std::set<Key>>::serialise(const std::set<Key> &x) {
  {
    const typename std::set<Key>::const_iterator x_cend = x.cend();

    for (typename std::set<Key>::const_iterator x_iterator = x.cbegin();
         x_iterator != x_cend; ++x_iterator)
      ::serialise(*x_iterator);
  }
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void Serialiser<std::pair<T1, T2>>::serialise(const std::pair<T1, T2> &x) {
  ::serialise(x.first);
  ::serialise(x.second);
}

template <typename Key, typename T>
void Serialiser<std::map<Key, T>>::serialise(const std::map<Key, T> &x) {
  {
    const typename std::map<Key, T>::const_iterator x_cend = x.cend();

    for (typename std::map<Key, T>::const_iterator x_iterator = x.cbegin();
         x_iterator != x_cend; ++x_iterator)
      ::serialise(*x_iterator);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, std::set<int>> u {
    {5, {2, 3}},
    {7, {2, 3}}
  };
  serialise(u);
}
```

Output:

```
5
2
3
7
2
3
```